# Problem about gradients and directional derivatives

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and it is easy to observe that  $\operatorname{grad} f(a,b)$  is always perpendicular to the tangent line at point $(a,b)$ and I just can't prove why it would be like that.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled. Are you looking at the surface $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 = z\}$, or are you looking at the circle $y = \pm\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$ for some fixed $r > 0$ and $x\in[-r, r]$? In either case, it doesn't quite matter; in the former case you have a tangent plane, in the latter - a tangent line. For the line case, compute the gradient and take the inner product of the gradient with the tangent vector, and observe that it is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are essentially trying to show the following

> $(\nabla f) \perp (f=c)$, which is that the gradient of the function is perpendicular to the level surface (f = constant).

Consider in general a curve $r=r(t)$ that stays on the level surface $f=c$. By definition $v = \frac{dr}{dt}$ is tangent to the level curve $f=c$. By the chain rule, the total differential $\frac{df}{dt}$ gives,
$$\frac{df}{dt} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \cdot \frac{dz}{dt} = \nabla f \cdot \frac{dr}{dt} = \nabla f \cdot v = 0$$
since $f(t)=c$. So, the gradient vector $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to $v$. This is true for any motion on $f=c$, and $v$ can be any vector tangent to $f=c$.

So, given any vector $v$ tangent to the level curve, $\nabla f \perp v$, so $\nabla f \perp$ tangent plane.

Let me know if you need clarification about anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the assumption is that $f(x,y)$ can be parametrized by a continuously differentiable function in a neighborhood $I$ of a point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the domain wrt to a parameter, say $t$ as

$r(t)=x(t)i+jy(t)$ such that it has a non-zero tangent vector, say $r'(t)$ and that If $t\epsilon I,$ $f(r(t))=c$, where c is a constant.

Hence, $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt} f(r(t))=\nabla{f(r(t)).r'(t)}=0.$

Thus, gradient of $f(r(t))$ i.e. of $f(x,y)$ is perpendicular to the tangent at the level curve at any given point $(x_0,y_0)$.

Take a look at this link

http://poncelet.math.nthu.edu.tw/disk3/cal01/tg.pdf